# Using checkbox to determine session or cookie - php

Tags: php, html

Right.. So i have this little proglem with my code. I get an all familiar ' Undefined index ' on a checkbox not checked. The thing I want to achieve is as follows: If checked - use cookies, if not - use sessions. Let me post the code fer ye.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="remember_me"/>Remember me!
```

PHP:

```
if ($login_ok == true)
{
    if ($remember_me == "on")
        setcookie('username', $username, time() + 7200);
    else if ($remember_me = "")
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    header('Location: userprofile.php');
    exit();
 }
 else {
     die ('Wrong userrrname / password');
 }
```

Comment: how u r getting $remember_me  value ?

Comment: Where do you set `$remember_me`?

Comment: $remember_me = $_POST['remember_me'];

Comment: You're aware that sessions generally (almost always, unless you want to pass the session ID in the querystring, which is frowned upon) use cookies, right? So there doesn't seem to be much point in what you're doing.

Comment: You're assigning `else if ($remember_me = "")` instead of comparing `else if ($remember_me == "")`

Comment: are you doing a session_start() before using the $_SESSION var?

Comment: @LarsHarald how you set $remember_me is the issue, see my answer

Comment: You also need to declare it. I.e.: `else if ($_POST['remember_me'] = "")` or `$remember_me=$_POST['remember_me'];` then do `else if ($remember_me = "")`

Comment: yes i am. that doesnt look like the proglem

Comment: You can't use `if ($remember_me == "on")` because you don't have a `value` set for it yet, therefore it will always return false, in turn rendering the rest useless. You need to either use `value="on"` or check if it's "set". You're best using a ternary operator for this.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="remember_me" value="on" />Remember me!`

Comment: Thanks a bunch mateys! 
$remember_me = isset($_POST['remember_me'])?$_POST['remember_me']:'';

This did the trick! :)

Comment: No problemo @LarsHarald The "ternary operator" did the trick; *knew it* cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html forms do NOT send values for unchecked checkboxes.

Where you  have:

```
$remember_me = $_POST['remember_me'];
```

You will get the undifined index error is remember_me checkbox is unchecked.

Change to

```
$remember_me = isset($_POST['remember_me'])?$_POST['remember_me']:'';
```

This sets the variable to an empty string if the checkbox is unchecked, allowing the rest of your code to function.

That aside, sessions use cookies to function

Comment: Thanks a ton for that one! Been ogling google for hours. The little things in life..

Comment: A.K.A. "ternary operator" ;-) effective.

Answer (score 0):

Your setting the $remember_me variable in the else if statement

Change this

```
$remember_me = ""
```

To this

```
$remember_me == ""
```

Comment: still getting the notice